# CouchDB filtering on key array

Tags: nosql, couchdb

Given a CouchDb view that emits like this:

```
emit([doc.name, doc.date], doc)
```

How to filter on multiple `doc.name` values? Below doesn't seem to work.

```
keys=[["name1",{}],["name2",{}],["name3",{}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you specify the keys parameter, you are specifying an exact match.  Assuming you want a range query (every document with name="name1" no matter the date) then you need to query with a startkey and an endkey:

```
?startkey=["name1", ""]&endkey=["name1", {}]
```

And will have to repeat the query for each name.

Comment: Is it definite that this cannot be achieved in single query?